# How to access a bool from one script to another so I can load in multiple scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I'm a noob at unity and I'm trying to make a game where you come to an area and when you walk over an invincible box I have placed another scene loads in. And it will keep on going like that. In every scene you load in there will be another box to load the next scene in. But it will also unload scenes that are not directly behind you. So i you where to walk forwards, you would load 2 scenes infron of you and have 1 scenes loaded behind you.
I have done this since my game lags because of the amount of assets I have in the game and the graphics on them.

If it helps I'm using HDRP to make this game and all scenes are in front of each other so there is no bend to the map.

What I have come up with so far is using the box and adding a trigger on it to activate a bool that will load the next scene in a different script since that script has already a part where it loads a scene.

Any ideas on how to solve it or how to get the bool component from one script to another since it is triggered by a box collider. So when the box collider gets triggered you set the bool to true and the next scene loads in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Singleton pattern to send and keep data between scene.
Here is one template has you didn't put code.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public static GameManager Instance;
      public bool myBool; //here you can declare all the things you want

  
      void Awake()
      {
  
          if (instance != null && instance != this)
              Destroy(this.gameObject);
          else
          {
              instance = this;
              DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); //allow the script to not be destroyed when switching scene
          }
      }
  }
```

Then, if you want to call this class from another  class you just have to do this :

```
GameManager.Instance.myBool;
```